# How does the '&' operator work?

Tags: elixir

I am having trouble understand the '&' operator in the following context.

```
  @doc "Marks a task as executed"
  def put_task(task, project) do
    item = {task, project}
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, &MapSet.put(&1, item))
  end
```

It seems that in this case the '&1' is referring to the map object itself, but I am curious as to how this works. Is it passing itself in as an argument I looked into this in the docs but couldn't find out if this was exactly what was going on. I would be grateful if somebody could help me understand what is exactly going on and what &1 refers to and if it refers to the MapSet how is this possible.

Comment: That's equivalent to `fn x -> MapSet.put(x, item) end`. I'm sure there's an existing question about this here on StackOverflow but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: My question is what is x in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there two kinds of functions in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011784/why-are-there-two-kinds-of-functions-in-elixir)

Comment: Link to pertinent doc:
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1
Read the section "Anonymous functions"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would be grateful if somebody could help me understand what is exactly going on and what &1 refers to and if it refers to the MapSet how is this possible.

[`Agent.update/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Agent.html#update/3) calls the given function with the current state, and stores the returned value as the new state. Since `&MapSet.put(&1, item)` is the same as `fn x -> MapSet.put(x, item) end`, `x` here becomes the old state, and the new `MapSet` returned by `MapSet.put/2` becomes the new state of the agent.

For this code to function, there must be a call to `Agent.start` or `Agent.start_link` with `name: __MODULE__` and a function that returns `{:ok, map_set}` where `map_set` is any `MapSet` somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 25):

The `&1` is the first argument of the function. The whole `&` notation is basically an alternative way to express anonymous functions - there's nothing specific to `Enum` or `Agent` about it. Let's take this example:

```
fn (x, y, z) -> (x + z) * y end
```

This is an anonymous function that takes 3 arguments, adds the first and third one and multiplies the result by the second one. With the `&` notation:

```
&((&1 + &3) * &2)
```

Think of the `&1`, `&2` and `&3` as placeholders in an expression where the arguments will go. So when you do

```
Agent.update(__MODULE__, &MapSet.put(&1, item))
```

You're calling `Agent.update` with a one-argument function that calls `MapSet.put` with that argument and item - whatever that is. It's equivalent to:

```
Agent.update(__MODULE__, fn x -> MapSet.put(x, item) end)
```

Comment: I think this is much clearer than the accepted answer, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5):

Lets consider a more simple example,

```
Enum.map [1, 2, 3, 4], &(&1 * 2)

Enum.map [1, 2, 3, 5], fn x -> x * 2 end // Exactly like above
```

To `Enum.map` we are basically passing a list and an anonymous function. `Enum.map` expects the anonymous function to have atleast one argument(no brainer, it passes each element of the list to anonymous function). So  here `&1`  which is the first argument of the anonymous function which will be set by `Enum.map` when it calls our anonymous function. `Enum.map` loops through the list calling our anonymous function  each time with a different element of our list.

Though I do not know the implementation of the `Agent.update`, but as far as I see what its doing is, `Agent.update` is calling on the agent which is `_MODULE_` and on this applying function Map.Set which receives the old state of the agent, and sets new state of the agent. In other words you could say `&1` is the old state of the agent

Comment: So for the map it makes more sense to me I know that it will loop through 1 then 2 and so on. But above we are dealing with put. @Dogbert says that the code can be expresses as `fn x -> MapSet.put(x, item) end` which I wasn't confused about in the first place; rather I was confused about what is `x` in this case and if `x` is the MapSet object how is it getting this reference through `&1`. I should have been clearer in the question.