# What does "&1" mean in elixir function?

Tags: elixir

Given this function, what does `&1` refer to?

```
Enum.map [1, 2, 3, 4], &(&1 * 2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are there two kinds of functions in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011784/why-are-there-two-kinds-of-functions-in-elixir)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the '&' operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982351/how-does-the-operator-work)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`&1` refers to the first argument the callback function would receive. The ampersand by itself (`&`) is a shorthand for a captured function. This is how you could expand that function.

```
Enum.map([1, 2, 3, 4], fn x -> x * 2 end)
```

`fn ->` is equal to `&(...`

`x -> x` is equal to `...(&1`

A quick reference can be found [here](https://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#partials-and-function-captures-in-elixir)

Answer (score 15):

The `&(1 + &1)` syntax in elixir is simply another way to write an **anonymous function**.

So given the above:

```
fn(x) -> 1 + x end
```

Is identical to

```
&(1 + &1)
```

It's just another way of writing anonymous functions, typically used when you are doing a small unit of operation or simply calling another function.

Each `&n` when using that syntax, refers to the position of the arguments called in that function.

So:

```
fn(x, y, z) -> x + y + z end
```

Would mean that if you were to use the shorthand `&` anonymous function syntax:

- `x == &1` because `x` is the first argument
- `y == &2` because `y` is the second argument
- `z == &3` because `z` is the third argument

Another way of representing these arguments is by using the anonymous function + arity syntax which pretty much acts as a delegator.

So for example, lets say that you wanted to map over a list of values and apply a function each value. Using the basic anonymous function syntax, it would look like:

```
Enum.map([1, 2, 3], fn(x) -> add_one(x) end)
```

Using the `&` with argument captures (`&1`)

```
Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &(add_one(&1))
```

Using the `&` with arity matching:

```
Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &add_one/1)
```

Which simply says, that this anonymous function will take only 1 argument and that argument should be applied to the function called `add_one` which is also a 1 arity function.

So those three examples above are exactly the same and will all result in `add_one` being called on each argument.