# Convert struct to list in elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir. Currently using a Pheonix framework. I need to convert structs to list so I can use them in the select field.

In my `user_controller.ex` I attempt to convert a struct to list, but the variable `user_types_name` is always empty.

```
user_type_names = []
for user <- Accounts.list_user_types() do
     user_type_names ++ [user.name]
end
```

While in `form.html.eex`. For additional information

```
<%= inputs_for f, :user_type, fn cf -> %>
    <%= label cf, :user_type %>
    <%= select cf, :user_type, @user_type_names %>
    <%= error_tag cf, :user_type %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data in Elixir is immutable. `++` is a concatenation operator, not a way to mutate a list by pushing an item onto it.

You'll need to use something like this:

```rb
user_type_names = Accounts.list_user_types()
  |> Enum.map(fn(user) -> user.name end)
```

Or, more concisely:

```rb
user_type_names = Accounts.list_user_types()
  |> Enum.map(&(&1.name))
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion and it worked, thanks. But I'm a bit lost when you used ```Enum.map(&(&1.name))```, can you elaborate it to me?

Comment: @NJY404 see here: [What does "&1" mean in elixir function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067455/what-does-1-mean-in-elixir-function)

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps look at Enum.map

```
Enum.map(1..3, fn x -> x * 2 end)
[2, 4, 6]
```

Enum.map returns a list by itself, so you might want do something like

```
user_type_names = Enum.map(Accounts.list_user_types()...)
```

and this should return a list.

Documentation is pretty well written : https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html

Elixir forces you to think about what module ( Enum ) and what **function** ( map ) you are going to use. Think functional is the key to make things work

Answer (score 1):

In Elixir, `for` is a construct for comprehensions. Meaning that the result will be a list built with the result of the `do` clause for each element in the enumerables you use.

So, in your example, you are in fact building a list where each element is the concatenation of `user_type_names` (which every time is the empty list you assigned) with the current `user.name`.

What was suggested about assigning won't really work inside the `for`'s `do` clause, because of the scoping rules. You will be reassigning it but the result will actually be the same, because it will still be the result of the match (`=`).

The solution is actually far simpler than what you're doing. It's enough to do:

```rb
user_type_names = for user <- Accounts.list_user_types(), do: user.name
```