# Pass and consume a named function in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

The following Elixir code is incorrect but conveys (I think) the desired result:

```
defmodule Question do
  def dbl(n), do: n * 2
  def trp(n), do: n * 3

  def consumer(xs, f) do
    Enum.filter(xs, f.(x) > 5)
  end
end

Question.consumer([1, 2, 3], dbl) # [3]
Question.consumer([1, 2, 3], trp) # [2, 3]
```

How should the `consumer` method be written to consume `dbl` and `trp` correctly? And then how would you call it?

Thank you!

EDIT:

A related question please. How would you write and call the Scala code below in Elixir:

```
def dbl(n: Int): Int = n * 2
def trp(n: Int): Int = n * 3

def consume(xs: List[Int], f: (Int) => Int): List[Int] =
  xs.filter(x => f(x) > 5)

consume(List(1, 2, 3), dbl) # List(3)
consume(List(1, 2, 3), trp) # List(2, 3)
```

(Thank you) * 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Elixir equivalent of Scala's `x => f(x) > 5` is `fn x -> f.(x) > 5 end`. This is how you use it:

```
defmodule Question do
  def dbl(n), do: n * 2
  def trp(n), do: n * 3

  def consumer(list, f) do
    Enum.filter(list, fn x -> f.(x) > 5 end)
  end
end
```

You can then call it using:

```
Question.consumer([1, 2, 3], &Question.dbl/1)   # => [3]
Question.consumer([1, 2, 3], &Question.trp/1)   # => [2, 3]
```

---

**Additional Notes:**

- You can also use the short-hand `&(f.(&1) > 5)` instead of the full function
- *Notice the `&` and `/1`  - You need to pass a complete reference to the named module methods. [See the Elixir guide on the Function captures](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#partials-and-function-captures-in-elixir)*.
- On the other hand, if you make the `dbl` and `trp` functions anonymous, you can pass them directly as arguments:

  ```
  dbl = fn n -> n * 2 end
  trp = fn n -> n * 3 end

  Question.consumer([1, 2, 3], dbl)   # => [3]
  Question.consumer([1, 2, 3], trp)   # => [2, 3]
  ```
- For reference, read: [Why are there two kinds of functions in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011784/why-are-there-two-kinds-of-functions-in-elixir?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you have a look at the edit please. I can't figure out how to use `Enum.filter` with a passed-in function. `Enum.filter(xs, f > 5)` does not seem to work?

Comment: I only want to filter the collection using the supplied function - no mapping - so the scala output of [2] and [2, 3] is what I'm after.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for your quick help - and just what I was looking for!