# Importance of . in the Anonymous Functions in Elixir functional programming

Tags: elixir, erlang-shell

I am new to [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/). While going through [Elixir School](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/basics/) online in the functions section, I found **`Anonymous Functions`**. In **Anonymous Functions,** the function definition is as follows

```
iex> sum = fn (a, b) -> a + b end
iex> sum.(2, 3)
     5
```

My question is what is the importance of **`.`** used while calling Anonymous functions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011784/why-are-there-two-kinds-of-functions-in-elixir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the `.` is very easy to explain.

Explaining it with your example, you have to the `.` to indicate to the compiler that `sum` is a identifier that describes a variable that contain a reference to function and not a identifier that describes a variable with a normal data type or a named function.

So, when you see a function being called using dot syntax, you will know its an anonymous function, rather than trying to find the regular function definition.